# Streaming PDF via invocation of HTTPHandler using $.get into object element

Tags: jquery, pdf, httphandler

What I am trying to do is invoke an HTTPHandler via the $.get method of jQuery which will stream back a PDF and display it in a web page using an object element. My previous method of setting the src attribute of an IFrame to be the result of a handler invocation works, but I would like cross-browser completion notification, so have moved to using $.get(). Sample code:

```
    function buttonClick() {

        $.get("/PDFHandler.ashx", {},

            function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                var pdfObjectString = "<object data='' type='application/pdf' width='600' height='600'></object>";
                var pdfObject = $(pdfObjectString);
                pdfObject.attr("data", data);
                $("#container").append(pdfObject);
            });
```

As you can see, I am attempting to stick the 'data' variable into an object element. This is not working (no error, PDF just doesn't display), presumably because the data that comes back is binary, yet the attr() method expects a string (I think).

My question is thus: how can I invoke an HTTPHandler via $.get and somehow assign the data from the callback to the data attribute of an object?

Comment: Why are you doing this? It means the whole PDF file gets loaded into JavaScript's memory, which can't be good. Why not simply write out an  `<object>` with the aspx URL?

Comment: Thanks, Pekka. However I do it it will end up in memory, but the reason I don't go with the URL approach is because I want some notification when the call has completed - my understanding is that the object element doesn't support the events that I would need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this question: [How to open a file using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761682/how-to-open-a-file-using-javascript) I was able to work out a solution. Essentially you call the handler again in the success callback function. I couldn't get it working with an `<object>` tag (still using an IFrame) but it is good enough for what I need.

For this to work the HTTP handler must be caching the results, otherwise it just gets invoked again.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled for hours to have something like this work, and this has been my very simple solution that works perfectly:

1. On the browser side, I have an iFrame contained in a DIV tag, but can be anywhere you want. You can change iFrame attributes to hide / show it on need basis.

```html
<div id = "divpayframe">
<iframe name="payframe" id="payframe" width="600" height="800" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

2. I also have a form that uses the normal submit to the server, but specifies the target as iFrame.

```html
<form id="frmpayslip" method="post" action="/payslip" target="payframe">
```

3. The server returns a pdf stream and sets the response content type to application/pdf. See below code  (Written in Delphi)

   Var
   S: TMemoryStream;

   //Some code generate the pdf file on the server side and convert it to a pdf file stream
   //Assign the stream to the variable S and set the Response to return the stream

   Response.ContentType := 'application/pdf';
   Response.SendStream(S);

Note, no custom headers required for this unless you want to send it as attachment instead, in which case you can send 'Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="payslip.pdf"' to achieve the same result.