# Write the PDF stream into iFrame using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, iframe

I am using `$.post(url, function(data){ // I use data here });` The data I get from post is a PDF stream (response content type is application/pdf). I have an iframe in which I must display this PDF. Target browser is IE7 & IE8.

One solution is to submit a form and give the target as iFrame. However, I am having difficulty verifying whether it is really the PDF or custom designed not-found-error page (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741593/detecting-onload-event-in-ie-for-iframe-which-has-pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

I've done this. What I did was check:

```
if (data.toLowerCase().substr(0, 4) == "%pdf")
```

If that evaluates to true, you should have a PDF, otherwise the content will be whatever the server sends back on error.

In [Streaming PDF via invocation of HTTPHandler using $.get into object element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847742/streaming-pdf-via-invocation-of-httphandler-using-get-into-object-element) I was trying to do something similar.

The first step was to make the Ajax call - this will be your `$.post(url, function(data){ // I use data here });` - then check the result as I suggested above.

If the PDF returned without error: `$('#iframe_id')[0].src = 'url'`. The trick is that by exploiting browser caching, setting the source of the IFrame will display the cached PDF and not resend the request for it.

For the caching to will work, you will need to make sure that the `url` you use to request the PDF is the same both times.

Comment: Yes. But I need to display the PDF within iFrame