# How do I output EXCEL file directly to user without storing locally?

Tags: php, ajax, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to generate excel files (crazy right ?) with information I get from a database, the thing is whenever I create the file it is saved in the server and then I just send a link to that file to the user so he can access it.

I doubt this is the right way of doing it, what I'm looking for is to just send the file to the browser without saving it on the server.

**How do I output EXCEL file directly to user without storing locally?**

Code:

```
$fileName  = "Request_" . $idRequest . "_Update.xls";
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save($fileName);
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);


echo json_encode(array(
        "ExitCode" => 0,
        "Message" => "Success",            
        "data" => $request,
        "File" => "../reports/$fileName"
    ));
```

Once i receive `File` in the `$.ajax` call that receives it just add it to an anchor tag:

```
$.ajax({
       ...
       success : function(response){
           $('#container').append('<a href="'+response.File+'">Here is your file</a>
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761682/how-to-open-a-file-using-javascript) shows how to handle a success response be offering the file for download, or a failure response handled by the js (e.g. displayed within the current html page) without mime type issues

Comment: Would that answer be compatible across multiple browsers ? I've just used Ajax with jQuery

Comment: No guarantees - I'm not a js or browser expert, but it's the best answer I can come up with and looks as though it should work

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely try it and I'll let you know

Answer (score 2):

check this out.

```
//    reset all output buffering
    while (ob_get_level() > 0) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition:  inline; attachment; filename='.$filename);

    // we can't send any more headers after this
    flush();

    $excel = new PhpExcel();
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();
    // in this example, $data was an array in the format row => value
    //  data structure is not relevant to issue
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
         // add data to sheet here
         $sheet->SetCellValue('A' . $key, $value);
         // etc...
    }
    $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer($excel);
    // push to browser
    $writer->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a

`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.xls\"");`

to force download and then

`header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel");`

to say the browser that you're sending an excel file and finally just echo the file as an html `table`:

```
<?php
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.xls\"");
header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
echo "<html><table>...</table></html>";  // your table data here..
?>
```

Excel can open `.html` files with `<table>`s so there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please ?

Comment: @IsaacGonzalez Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok i get it now, but the thing is that since i do some other operations to the content in the file, i am not going to output everything as a `<table>` without re-doing a lot of my code. +1 for your help